# Adding a MapView to a custom view in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, view, android-mapview

I'm trying to add a MapView to a custom view that extends FrameLayout. This is my custom view:

```
public class LocationStepLayout extends FrameLayout implements StepLayout,OnMapReadyCallback{

private MapView mMapView;

private void initStepLayout(LocationStep step) {

   ...

   LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
   inflater.inflate(R.layout.location_layout,this,true);
   mMapView = findViewById(R.id.myMap);
   mMapView.getMapAsync(this);

  ...
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.852, 151.211);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney)
            .title("Marker in Sydney"));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

}
```

And this is my layout:

```
 <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/myMap"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:context="com.example.mapwithmarker.MapsMarkerActivity">

</com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>
```

But the map won't show on the view. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you post the code where you add the `LocationStepLayout`? Does it have a height?

Comment: @Klone I'm sorry - I don't understand what you mean

Comment: @ChristinaTsangouri Did you find any solution?